# create AsyncTask for Android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Can I know how to create AsyncTask for Android from all of these? I would like to remove the buttons and let all of these run in the background then redirect to the MainPage.java after clicking Logout.

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnDelete = (Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
    Button btnSignUp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
    Button btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomePage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SignUp.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            cDB.resetTables();
            mDB.resetTables();
            db.resetTables();
            pDB.resetTables();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: 1st: no idea what you want 2nd: if you want AsyncTask: google it

Comment: you should explain more clear what do you want.

Answer (score 1):

here is one AsyncTask Example. This will show a peogress dialog while executing the task.

```
private class LoginProcessing extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {
             private LoginCredentials myLoginCredentials;
             private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

             public LoginProcessing(LoginCredentials Credentials) {
                    super();
                    myLoginCredentials=Credentials;
             }

             protected void onPreExecute (){
                 progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Please Wait...",true);
             }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Object... arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                //Code to do the process in background
                return null;        
            } 
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                //Your code after the process   
            }

         }
```

You can call this Task as,

```
new LoginProcessing(loginCredentials).execute();
```

In this Example **loginCredentials** is the parameter I am passing to the AsyncTask. You can change it to your own parameter.